# BooleanWidget is not defined in django-filter

Tags: django, django-filter

I tried to create boolean widget following [django-filter documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/widgets.html)
However, I got error

> name 'BooleanWidget' is not defined

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? or what is causing this problem?
I also add filter part below.

```
class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    user=django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="iexact")
    project=django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="icontains")
    good=django_filters.BooleanFilter(widget=BooleanWidget())
    final = django_filters.BooleanFilter(widget=BooleanWidget())

    class Meta:
        model=html
        fields=['program','location','certificate']
```

Answer (score 2):

You should import widget class first:

```
from django_filters.widgets import BooleanWidget

class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    user=django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="iexact")
    project=django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="icontains")
    good=django_filters.BooleanFilter(widget=BooleanWidget())
    final = django_filters.BooleanFilter(widget=BooleanWidget())

    class Meta:
        model=html
        fields=['program','location','certificate']
```